# Apply SQL query condition to multiple columns in VBA

Tags: mysql, excel, vba, ado

Please find my below sample table,where i have applying if condition for multiplying Numerical data.

[image]

**Query Code**

```
sql_string = "Select [Sheet5$].[num] * IIf(([Sheet5$].[to]-[Sheet5$].[frm])<365, .4," & _
"IIf(([Sheet5$].[to]-[Sheet5$].[frm])>365, 1, 0)) from [Sheet5$]"
```

Above code will help me out to apply the condition on one column **i.e num** only.But i want to apply it on multiple columns around 20-30 columns which is available in my actual data.it is possible to mention column names but it is  not possible to write the above **if condition** to each column. please guide me on the same.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
Public Sub test()
Dim sql_string As String
Dim sheet_name As String

    sheet_name = "Sheet5$"

    sql_string = "Select "
    sql_string = sql_string & GetField(sheet_name, "num") & ","
    sql_string = sql_string & GetField(sheet_name, "num1") & ","
    sql_string = sql_string & GetField(sheet_name, "num2") & ","
    sql_string = sql_string & GetField(sheet_name, "num3")
    sql_string = sql_string & " from [" & sheet_name & "]"

    Debug.Print sql_string

End Sub

Public Function GetField(ByVal sheet_name As String, ByVal fieldName As String)

    GetField = "[" & sheet_name & "].[" & fieldName & "] * IIf(([" & sheet_name & "].[to] - [" & sheet_name & "].[frm]) < 365, 0.4, IIf(([" & sheet_name & "].[to] - [" & sheet_name & "].[frm]) > 365, 1, 0))"

End Function
```

Result:

```
Select [Sheet5$].[num] * IIf(([Sheet5$].[to] - [Sheet5$].[frm]) < 365, 0.4, IIf(([Sheet5$].[to] - [Sheet5$].[frm]) > 365, 1, 0)),
    [Sheet5$].[num1] * IIf(([Sheet5$].[to] - [Sheet5$].[frm]) < 365, 0.4, IIf(([Sheet5$].[to] - [Sheet5$].[frm]) > 365, 1, 0)),
    [Sheet5$].[num2] * IIf(([Sheet5$].[to] - [Sheet5$].[frm]) < 365, 0.4, IIf(([Sheet5$].[to] - [Sheet5$].[frm]) > 365, 1, 0)),
    [Sheet5$].[num3] * IIf(([Sheet5$].[to] - [Sheet5$].[frm]) < 365, 0.4, IIf(([Sheet5$].[to] - [Sheet5$].[frm]) > 365, 1, 0)) from [Sheet5$]
```